# Strange white line problems in tables columns with background

Tags: html, css, mobile, tablet

In short I have a website, that has strange white lines while scaling with touch screen devices. Website mostly uses tables for design. All of these problems happen on **td** element and side is pretty random (bottom, top, left, right.) The question is quite similar to one posted few year ago problem: [Thin gray black lines on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780896/thin-gray-black-lines-on-web-page-viewed-with-ipad), but the difference here is that I don't have divs next to each other. I could resolve one of them by using background color and rounded corners instead of multiple backgrounds, but I can't use them everywhere, because background on website can't be done with CSS gradient.

So what I have confirmed:

- Problem can be fixed by changing background picture to color.
- Some occurrences happen where  doesn't have neighbour.
- More I zoom in, more or longer stripes can be seen.
- All of these td-s, which have problem have background picture, but
  not all td elements with pictures have strange white lines.

I can't replicate problem with minimized page of website, so I can't post jsfiddle, but I can post a small html (problem occurrences between td tags) :

```
<table id="messages" class="default dark">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="left_top">works</td>
         <td class="mid_top">top line</td>
         <td class="right_top">works</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="left">line on left</td>
         <td class="problematic">bottom line</td>
         <td class="right">line on left</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="left_bottom">works</td>
         <td class="mid_bottom">works</td>
         <td class="right_bottom">works</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here's your problem: You're using tables for layout in 2013.

Comment: Unfortunately don't have time to redesign the website. Until that time, I need a quick fix.